# how to give border to multiple containers in a ListView with click on any of them?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a ListView.builder that creates several containers. it is used for filtering products by color in an eCommerce app. I want to give the containers border when the user taps the color. it looks something like this:
https://dribbble.com/shots/5569127
here is what I have tried now, but it does not give border to the containers on every click:

```
Color tileColor = Colors.lime;
  List<String> availableColors = ["red", "blue", "black", "brown", "violet"];

Container(
      height: 50,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: availableColors.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          bool showBorder = false;
          if (availableColors[index] == "red") {
            tileColor = Colors.red;
          }
          if (availableColors[index] == "blue") {
            tileColor = Colors.blue;
          }
          if (availableColors[index] == "black") {
            tileColor = Colors.black;
          }
          if (availableColors[index] == "brown") {
            tileColor = Colors.brown;
          }
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  print("object");
                  showBorder = !showBorder;
                  print(showBorder);
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: tileColor,
                    border: showBorder ? Border.all(color: Colors.green , width: 5) : Border(),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    )
```

Comment: you cannot have one `showBorder` variable to control multiple items in your `ListView` - or maybe its your intention to have all the items with border or not?

Comment: no I just want the item that has been clicked to have a border. how can I achive that?

Comment: then use `int showBorder` not `bool showBorder` and compare its value to `int index` from the item builder

Comment: I am pretty new to flutter. could you please show me with code?

Comment: @geekymano - working code added as an answer.

Comment: @anmol.majhail still it does not show the border on tap for me. have you tested it with emulator?

Comment: yes - tested - uploaded the image also. @geekymano

Comment: I had a problem in my code, now I have fixed it and it works. but still one item can be chosen, how can I make it multiple colors?

Comment: i think the model class must have one more field, something like `bool isSelected;`

Comment: @geekymano - answer updated for multiple selections also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @pskink: use - `int showBorder` instead of `bool showBorder`

Code:

```
  int showBorder = 999999999;
  List<String> availableColors = ["red", "blue", "black", "brown", "violet"];

              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              height: 50,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: availableColors.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (availableColors[index] == "red") {
                    tileColor = Colors.red;
                  }
                  if (availableColors[index] == "blue") {
                    tileColor = Colors.blue;
                  }
                  if (availableColors[index] == "black") {
                    tileColor = Colors.black;
                  }
                  if (availableColors[index] == "brown") {
                    tileColor = Colors.brown;
                  }
                  return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  print(index);
                  showBorder = index;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: tileColor,
                    border: showBorder == index
                        ? Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 5)
                        : Border(),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

For multiple selections. You have to save the tap index in the list.

Code:

```
  //  int showBorder = 999999999;
  List listBorder = [];
  List<String> availableColors = ["red", "blue", "black", "brown", "violet"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    listBorder.length = availableColors.length;
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: availableColors.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (availableColors[index] == "red") {
              tileColor = Colors.red;
            }
            if (availableColors[index] == "blue") {
              tileColor = Colors.blue;
            }
            if (availableColors[index] == "black") {
              tileColor = Colors.black;
            }
            if (availableColors[index] == "brown") {
              tileColor = Colors.brown;
            }
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    print(index);
                    listBorder.insert(index, index);
                  //  showBorder = index;
                    print(listBorder[index]);
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: tileColor,
                      border: listBorder[index] == index
                          ? Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 5)
                          : Border(),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]